# Returning result as JSON instead of HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, json

I am calling and displaying a java web service using ASP.NET Web API. How do i make it such that when i run my ASP.NET Web API, the page shows JSON data instead of HTML?

Here are my codes:

DemoRestfulClient.cs

```
public class DemoRestfulClient
{
    private string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
    public Task<string> AdditionJava2()
    {
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("AdditionJava2").Result;  
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.html");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

DemoController.cs

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private DemoRestfulClient demoRestfulClient = new DemoRestfulClient();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Result1 = demoRestfulClient.AdditionJava2().Result;
        return Content(Result1);
    }
}
```

Someone please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private DemoRestfulClient demoRestfulClient = new DemoRestfulClient();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Result1 = demoRestfulClient.AdditionJava2().Result;
        return Json(Result1);
    }
}
```

The above method will return a json object .
You have wanted to get the json object, right? :)

You have to parse the Json object in order to separately view the content in json.

By using ajax, you can get the content of the json object separately.

For an example,

```
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: $("#head").val() + "/Template/updatedTmpltView",
                                            dataType: "html",
                                            data: {},
                                            type: "POST",
                                            success: function (msg) {
                                               data = $.parseJSON(msg)
                                               var name = data.FieldName;
                                               var type = data.FieldType;
                                               var id = data.FieldId;
                                            },
                                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                            }
                                        });
```

In the **success** (msg), you get the json object as `**msg**`.

> **data** will include the parsed json object and you can obtain necessary data by data.**yourFieldName**

Hope this helped you! :)

Comment: Hi, thank u so much for helping me. I am still unsure of the AJAX part. Would u be able to help and guide me a bit more if i show u the java codes too?